# HttpContextBaseExtensions.GetOwinContext throws NullReferenceException when trying to run Unit tests

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4

I get a NullReferenceException when trying to run Unit tests for a program written in the ASP.NET MVC framework.

> Test(s) failed. System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.    at
>   System.Web.HttpContextBaseExtensions.GetOwinContext(HttpContextBase
>   context)

This error happens when I try to execute the `Logoff` method.

```
public ActionResult LogOff()
{
     SessionWrapper.SetInSession("_Settings", null);  
     AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
     return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}

public class HttpContextSessionWrapper : ISessionWrapper
{
        public T GetFromSession<T>(string key)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
                return (T)HttpContext.Current.Session[key];
            else    
                return default(T);
        }

        public void SetInSession(string key, object value)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
                HttpContext.Current.Session[key] = value;
        }
}
```

How do I fix this NullReferenceException when writing unit tests in ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Your original question was way too broad.  I edited it so it wouldn't be closed. This question is the right scope, but we still need some information: How are you mocking the HttpContextBase?  If you're not mocking the external classes, they're going to be null and you're going to get an NRE. You need to read up on a mocking framework like Rhino Mocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be using `HttpContext.Context`.  Use `this.Session`, this being your controller. You could either inject that with IoC or pass it to your methods.

With IoC, you could mock this dependency much easier as well.

Comment: Well.. Thank you for the input the first solution about `this.Session` is not working...  I will try IoC...